# Facing error while running "vcpkg install integrate" command on cmd

Tags: c, vcpkg

I just started coding in c but i facing some error while trying to install  libcurl using vcpkg
i tried running "vcpkg install integrate" which ended up giving error

## **ERROR**:

Computing installation plan...
error: while looking for integrate:x86-windows:
error: while loading integrate:
error: integrate does not exist

## **COMMAND USED**:

•vcpkg install integrate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.